# Where can I find the definition of the function PEM_read_bio_X509()?

Tags: linux, openssl

I am trying to find the C source code for the definition of the crypto function `PEM_read_bio_X509()`. See for example [this](http://www.zedwood.com/article/c-libssl-verify-x509-certificate) application in C++. I thought it would be part of the `openssl` [source code](https://github.com/openssl/openssl). But if I do:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:openssl/openssl.git
$ cd openssl
$ find . -type f -exec grep -I -Hn --color=auto PEM_read_bio_X509 {} \;
```

I get some matches, but only *use* cases, not the definition of the function.

I can also generate the shared library (`libcrypto.so`):

```
$ ./config
$ make
$ nm -g ./libcrypto.so | grep PEM_read_bio_X509
00000000001cb050 T PEM_read_bio_X509
00000000001cb0f0 T PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX
00000000001c6070 T PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL
00000000001c5f70 T PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ
```

So the symbol `PEM_read_bio_X509` is indeed defined in the generated `libcrypto.so`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where can I find the definition of the function PEM_read_bio_X509()?

I believe `PEM_read_bio_X509` is spliced together with macros. In particular, `DECLARE_PEM_rw(X509, X509)` (declaration) and `IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw(X509, X509, PEM_STRING_X509, X509)` (implementation).

```
$ cat include/openssl/pem.h | grep X509
# define PEM_STRING_X509_OLD     "X509 CERTIFICATE"
# define PEM_STRING_X509         "CERTIFICATE"
# define PEM_STRING_X509_TRUSTED "TRUSTED CERTIFICATE"
# define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ_OLD "NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
# define PEM_STRING_X509_REQ     "CERTIFICATE REQUEST"
# define PEM_STRING_X509_CRL     "X509 CRL"
STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio(BIO *bp, STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *sk,
int PEM_X509_INFO_write_bio(BIO *bp, X509_INFO *xi, EVP_CIPHER *enc,
STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *PEM_X509_INFO_read(FILE *fp, STACK_OF(X509_INFO) *sk,
DECLARE_PEM_rw(X509, X509)
DECLARE_PEM_rw(X509_AUX, X509)
DECLARE_PEM_rw(X509_REQ, X509_REQ)
DECLARE_PEM_write(X509_REQ_NEW, X509_REQ)
DECLARE_PEM_rw(X509_CRL, X509_CRL)
DECLARE_PEM_rw(PKCS8, X509_SIG)
```

And:

```
$ grep -IR -A 2 DECLARE_PEM_rw ./* | grep define -A 2
./include/openssl/pem.h:# define DECLARE_PEM_rw(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_read(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_write(name, type)
./include/openssl/pem.h:# define DECLARE_PEM_rw_const(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_read(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_write_const(name, type)
./include/openssl/pem.h:# define DECLARE_PEM_rw_cb(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_read(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        DECLARE_PEM_write_cb(name, type)
```

And:

```
$ grep -IR -A 2 DECLARE_PEM_read ./* | grep define -A 2
./include/openssl/pem.h:#  define DECLARE_PEM_read_fp(name, type) /**/
./include/openssl/pem.h-#  define DECLARE_PEM_write_fp(name, type) /**/
./include/openssl/pem.h-#  define DECLARE_PEM_write_fp_const(name, type) /**/
--
./include/openssl/pem.h:#  define DECLARE_PEM_read_fp(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        type *PEM_read_##name(FILE *fp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
./include/openssl/pem.h-
--
./include/openssl/pem.h:#  define DECLARE_PEM_read_bio(name, type) \
./include/openssl/pem.h-        type *PEM_read_bio_##name(BIO *bp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);
```

---

You should be able to see the implementation in [`crypto/pem/pem_x509.c`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/pem/pem_x509.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "internal/cryptlib.h"
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pkcs7.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

IMPLEMENT_PEM_rw(X509, X509, PEM_STRING_X509, X509)
```

That's not very useful. So preprocess the source file with `-E` (instead of compiling with `-c`):

```
$ cd openssl
$ ./config
...

# No good...
$ make CFLAGS="-I include -E" crypto/pem/pem_x509.o
gcc -I include -E -c -o crypto/pem/pem_x509.o crypto/pem/pem_x509.c

# Try again manually...
$ gcc -I include -E -o crypto/pem/pem_x509.i crypto/pem/pem_x509.c
```

And then:

```
$ grep PEM_read_bio_X509 crypto/pem/pem_x509.i
X509 *PEM_read_bio_X509(BIO *bp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u); X509 *
PEM_read_X509(FILE *fp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u); int PEM_write_b
io_X509(BIO *bp, X509 *x); int PEM_write_X509(FILE *fp, X509 *x);
X509 *PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX(BIO *bp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u); X5
09 *PEM_read_X509_AUX(FILE *fp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u); int PEM
_write_bio_X509_AUX(BIO *bp, X509 *x); int PEM_write_X509_AUX(FILE *fp, X509 *x)
;
X509_REQ *PEM_read_bio_X509_REQ(BIO *bp, X509_REQ **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void
 *u); X509_REQ *PEM_read_X509_REQ(FILE *fp, X509_REQ **x, pem_password_cb *cb, v
oid *u); int PEM_write_bio_X509_REQ(BIO *bp, X509_REQ *x); int PEM_write_X509_RE
Q(FILE *fp, X509_REQ *x);
X509_CRL *PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL(BIO *bp, X509_CRL **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void
 *u); X509_CRL *PEM_read_X509_CRL(FILE *fp, X509_CRL **x, pem_password_cb *cb, v
oid *u); int PEM_write_bio_X509_CRL(BIO *bp, X509_CRL *x); int PEM_write_X509_CR
L(FILE *fp, X509_CRL *x);
X509 *PEM_read_bio_X509(BIO *bp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u){ return
 PEM_ASN1_read_bio((d2i_of_void *)d2i_X509, "CERTIFICATE",bp,(void **)x,cb,u); }
 X509 *PEM_read_X509(FILE *fp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u){ return P
EM_ASN1_read((d2i_of_void *)d2i_X509, "CERTIFICATE",fp,(void **)x,cb,u); } int P
EM_write_bio_X509(BIO *bp, X509 *x) { return PEM_ASN1_write_bio((i2d_of_void *)i
2d_X509,"CERTIFICATE",bp,x,
```

You are interested in the last hit (reformatted):

```
X509 *PEM_read_bio_X509(BIO *bp, X509 **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u)
{
    return PEM_ASN1_read_bio((d2i_of_void *)d2i_X509, "CERTIFICATE",bp,(void **)x,cb,u);
}
```

Lather, rinse, repeat for `PEM_ASN1_read_bio`.

Comment: Thanks! What does the last line mean: `type *PEM_read_bio_##name(BIO *bp, type **x, pem_password_cb *cb, void *u);`. I guess `type` is a `typedef`? But still this looks like a prototype. So where is the real definition of `PEM_read_bio_X509()`?

Comment: @Håkon - I added additional information that shows you how to preprocess the source file and see what the macro expands to.